# How to add a Package into my jar file

Tags: java, jar, package

I want to make a jar file with all the classes needed for an application to run. Some of these classes are into an package folder, for educational purposes.

Can I make a jar file including the package folder? How?

Should I compress the package into a Jar and then also insert it into my upper level jar? If so, could I simply do import package.class?

Example:

```
// package
  class1.class
  class2.class
..
mainclass.class
manifest.mf

jar cfvm MyJar manifest.mf *.class;
```

Comment: I dont think it matters if they are in different packages... as long as you go to the lowest most package `folder` and do `\*.class` it will recurisvely add them all up

Comment: Posted pal. Which one worked may i ask?

Comment: The second one. I did it before but forgot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of what you do there... just do `directory\*.class` or you can even do `directory\` and i believe that would still work